Opentext Enterprise Connect change max size of downloadable files
We'd like to download files using enterprise connect by opentext.
The max size seems to be 250 MB per file.
We don't find anything on the admin pages where to change this value.
We are using the "send to desktop" function as nothing else is offered.
